# Camera: "Linear" zoom

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, camera, zooming

I want to move a camera closer to an object in Unity, so that the zooming is linear. Take a look at the zooming in the Scene window in the Unity Editor. The camera isn't moving with a constant speed. The more zoomed in you are, the slower the camera moves. And I do want to move the camera, I don't want to change the FOV.

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, yes do not use the FOV to do that, it would be a massive pain to control the movement. Being in low FOV, would mean you are focus on a tiny part and movement would be hard to control since one unit would be a large movement in small FOV. Also, a large FOV creates fish eye effect. So nope.

One way you could achieve this fast to slow effect is to use a distance to define the amount of movement

Let's consider you use the mouse wheel to zoom in and out, you listens to the value and create a movement based on that.

```
float movement = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
if(movement == 0) 
{
    return;
}
Transform camTr = Camera.main.transform;
float distance = Vector3.Distance(camTr.position, origin.position) + 1;
camTr.Translate(camTr.forward * distance * movement * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

speed variable is meant to control how fast regardless of the distance. Distance gets a plus 1 so you can still move while real close to the origin.

The origin position needs to be defined, it could be based on a raycast going forward from the camera and hitting at y = 0. Just an idea. It could also be a focused object, that all depends on what you are doing.

The whole point here is that your camera will move faster if you are far from the focus point. Also, you may want to clamp the movement so that begin far away does not result in gigantic movement.

Answer (score 0):

i propose you to use FOV (because player feel good)

1- use [Transform.localPosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html) to change distance of camera to near or far - you should change z axis to changing distance of camera

2- use camera rendertotexture and in GUI change scale of it ( isn't good because need pro unity license and get allot of memory);


but can't know whats reason for you want forget changing FOV

Comment: Changing the FOV is not real good here. That would mean that you are sniping a tiny zone when small FOV and as a result, movement becomes cumbersome. Also, at large FOV, you get a fish eye effect. Moving the camera in space is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

One step of perspective projection of a point is the division by distance of that point. This means that the projected size of any object does not change linearly with its distance.

```
projectedSize = originalSize / distance
```

So if you want to approach an object in a way that its projected size grows linearly, you'll have to change your distance non-linearly.

We do this by also dividing the distance by some value `f`. The exact value of `f` depends on the stepSize and (I think) the FoV of your camera.

By using FixedUpdate() instead of Update() we make sure we have a constant stepSize which allows us to assume `f` as being constant as well.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    newDistance = oldDistance / f;
}
```

For the definition of `f` you can use any value bigger than, but close to 1. For example `f = 1.01f`. This will approximate the desired behaviour quite well. If you want it to be perfectly linear, you'll have to dig deeper into the calculations behind perspective projection and calculate the exact value of `f` yourself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection